# PHP Symfony 1.4 page only accessible on fontend_dev.php

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I am working using PHP symfony 1.4. 
The problem I have is the following: I created my page/template but even when i put it in production, the page is unaccessible. But it is only accessible through frontend_dev.php.

I cleared the cache, i created the action and the template, i created the route.

What could be the problem, could it come from the event dispatcher ?

Comment: Did you configure Apache or Nginx?

Comment: Does your project use a database?  It could be that the dev environment uses a different database account, so it works.  Check the Symfony log files and web server logs for errors.